# Array of objects declaration

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop

I am a bit confused with the 2 lines below.

```
MyClass myobj[];
myobj = new MyClass[numberVariable];
```

i would expect in line 1 something like:

```
MyClass[] myobj;
```

But the code works and there is not error.

What is the explanation?

Comment: Different ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) states

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both.

So even this is possible

```
float[][] f[][], g[][][], h[];
```

which is equivalent to

```
float[][][][] f;
float[][][][][] g;
float[][][] h;
```

and this is more readable, isn't it?

Comment: It gets worse than that. `public static int[]foo()[] { return new int[10][10];}` is valid too...

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid syntax in Java, though `MyClass[] myobj` makes more sense to me, since you are declaring an array of type `MyClass`.